# Get referrer within AWS Lambda@edge

Tags: amazon-web-services, referrer, aws-lambda-edge

Not seeing the referrer in the [documented event structure](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/lambda-event-structure.html#lambda-event-structure-request), and I haven't seen anything in the object in my test lambda - but that's not necessarily an accurate representation of a live request.

Is there a way to determine the referrer in the request inside a lambda@edge. Specifically, I'm working within the ClientRequest.

Comment: Thanks for selecting my answer.  I updated it below, you can whitelist it in the Cache Behaviour settings.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As per the AWS docs [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/RequestAndResponseBehaviorCustomOrigin.html#request-custom-headers-behavior), CloudFront removes the Referer header.  If you wish to forward your Referer header you can whitelist it in the Cache Behaviour settings here:

[image]